# How to presist data when my app updates its version

Tags: ios

Lets say I have an application in app store. Now I am sending an update with some new features and bug fixes. Users of old app have some app data stored in NSUserDefaults. And UUID is also being used. So bascially what will happen when they update the app ?

Will data be lost ?

UUID will be changed ?